# Multiple Statements in If Else in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to use if (condition) then Statement 1 , statement 2, ...  else statement 1, statement 2,... ;
in SML Programming Language.
I could not use and, simple space or ,. Any suggestions if this is possible at all?
note: I do not mean nested if else. It is pretty clear though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the construct `(expr1; expr2; ... ; exprn)` to execute multiple expressions sequentially. So:

```
if condition then (
  expression1;
  expression2
) else (
  expression1;
  expression2
)
```

Comment: It seems you can't put `;` after `expression2`